# Implementing a LinearLayout with only using java code in android

Tags: android-linearlayout

With having a main.xml file with

`<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget43"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100px"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tc_buttom_text1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Time elapsed"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tc_buttom_text2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="00:00:00 00"
>
</TextView>
<Button
android:id="@+id/tc2_home"
android:layout_width="70px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="200px"
android:layout_marginRight="10px"
android:text="Home"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
>
</Button>
</LinearLayout>`

is ok to gain a LinearLayout view by giving the path as

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Anyone can help me to do this same thing with only using java code?